# Understand whether any items are ranked significantly higher/lower in a survey using likert scale questions?

Tags: likert

Say I have a survey asking a single group of 50 participants to rank the importance of 10 different aspects of using a website.

E.g., How are important are the following when using a website:

1. How quickly the site loads
2. How easy it is to find what I'm looking for.
   etc.

The scale is 1 (Extremely unimportant) to 5 (extremely important).

I now want to understand if any factors stand out as significantly important or unimportant.

Can I simply compare mean scores across questions?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, your data are not "ranks" in the statistical sense, as the aspects are not brought into a rank order. Rather they are all assessed separately on a Likert scale.

Comment: @ChristianHennig Correct.

Each item would get its own score, and I would want to compare whether there is a significant difference between them.

E.g., Say item 1 has an average score of 3.4 on the Likert scale, item 2 is a 3.0, Item 3 is a 2.8, Item 4 is a 2.5, etc. 

Is item 1 significantly higher than all others, or is the difference negligible?

Comment: People may have different opinions on whether responses on a Likert scale can be treated as numerical values or not. There is a long and controversial discussion of this in the literature. So basically some would say yes and some would say no to your question whether you could compare the means. I'm curious myself on what answers you'll get. ;-)

Comment: Am I right that all questions are answered by the same persons, so that there is no independence between the different variables?

Comment: Correct @ChristianHennig, there is no independence between these questions. 
I would solely be looking for within-group differences (e.g., are the ratings between questions different)

Comment: If you run a formal test, you will need to take dependence into account.